# ejabberd: Error running Post Install Script

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I'm trying to install `ejabberd` on my pc but I keep getting this error:

```
Error running Post Install Script
The installation may not have completed correctly
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details ? Which installer are you using ? Which operating system are you using ? Can you find the installer log and grab some more information about your issue ?

Comment: Check the logs please ;)

Comment: I am facing the same problem, if you go to the ejabberd install.log scroll to the bottom, does it also say Error executing post installation script
/Applications/my-ejabberd/bin/postinstall.sh??? And you managed to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

ejabberd 15.07 has been released and is likely to have fix your issues with installer. You can download upgrade on [ejabberd Download page](https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads/).

Comment: unfortunately this issue still exist on window 8 and no help from log files