# Error: running post install script

Tags: installation, ejabberd, failed-installation

I am installing ejabberd using `ejabberd-16.09-windows-installer` but i am receiving

> Error running Post Install Script. Installation may have not completed
>   correcty

I am running `windows 10 x 64`. I searched for all possible solution and none works for me

What i have already tried

From [This post](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/1018) ->
Ensure i have `msvcrt100.dll`, run the installer as administrator

This [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31269714/ejabberd-error-running-post-install-script) -> Nothing

```
...
Installation logs
Creating Desktop Shortcut for Start ejabberd
Creating Desktop Shortcut for Stop ejabberd
Executing final installation script
Error executing post installation script
D:\ejabber\bin\postinstall.cmd
\Program ended with an error exit code
Creating Uninstaller
Creating uninstaller 25%
Creating uninstaller 50%
Creating uninstaller 75%
Creating uninstaller 100%
Uninstaller icon changed
Installation completed
Log finished 12/03/2016 at 13:23:36
```

Comment: did you try Ejabber install try that for windows easy to install and start and stop server

Comment: I don't think if i got your point @ShobhakarTiwari